# Linker breaks UIBarButtonItem bound with CommandParameter

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` bound to a MvvmCross command:

```cs
set.Bind(this.deleteItem).To(vm => vm.DeleteCommand).CommandParameter(this.deleteItem);
```

This works fine with the linker turned off. But if I set it to **Link SDK assemblies only**, the binding breaks and never gets fired. It silently fails, no errors or logged warnings.

Removing the CommandParameter and enabling the linker does work, however:

```cs
set.Bind(this.deleteItem).To(vm => vm.DeleteCommand);
```

Why does the binding break when the linker is enabled? I've made sure the linker is including `UIBarButtonItem.Clicked`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out: the linker was stripping ICommand's `CanExecuteChanged` event, which was used via reflection in `MvxWrappingCommand`.

The fix was to add an [XML linker configuration file](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/) with this:

```xml
<assembly fullname="System">
    <type fullname="System.Windows.Input.ICommand"></type>
</assembly>
```

Curiously adding a LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file referencing `CanExecuteChanged` didn't seem to preserve it, not sure why.